# Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package (ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 3:0-32)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, modulenotfounderror

## ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 3:0-32

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package...

Tried every possible solutions
Also Tried Reinstalling firebase and also node-modules still not working for me

Tried:
`npm i firebase`

also reinstalling firebase:
`npm uninstall firebase`
`npm install firebase@latest`

Comment: What was the command that gave you this error? How does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.